# How to handle (Google Forms - Spreadsheet) "Checkboxes" answers in SPSS

Tags: google-sheets, frequency, google-forms, spss

I am analyzing an electronic survey I made using Google Forms and I have the following problem.

One of the questions can take multiple answers in the form of Checkboxes as shown in the picture below. The question is in Greek so I have added some Choice1, Choice2, Choice3 etc next to each answer in order to facilitate my question.

[image]

In my data when someone chose lets say Choice1 and Choice2,
I will have an answer which is the concatenation of the strings he checked seperated with commas.

In this case it would be:

> Choice1, Choice2

If someone else checked Choice1, Choice2 and Choice4
his answer in my data would be:

> Choice1, Choice2, Choice4

The problem is SPSS has no way of seperating the substrings (seperated by commas) and understanding which Choices each case has in common. Or maybe there is a way but I don't know it :)

When I, for example, do a simple frequency analysis for this question it produces a table that perceives

> Choice1, Choice2

as a completely different case from

> Choice1, Choice2, Choice4

Ideally I would like to somehow tell SPSS to count the frequency of each unique Choice (Choice1, Choice2, Choice3 etc etc) rather than each unique combination of those Choices.
Is that possible? And if it is can you point me to the documentation I need to study to make it happen?

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you are working with the following data, which is a CSV file you have downloaded from your online form. Copy and paste the text below and save it to a text file named "CourseInterestSurvey.CSV".

```
Timestamp,Which courses are you interested in?,What software do you use?
12/28/2012 11:57:56,"Research Methods, Data Visualization","Gnumeric, SPSS, R"
12/28/2012 11:58:09,Data Visualization,"SPSS, Stata, R"
12/28/2012 11:59:09,"Research Dissemination, Graphic Design",Adobe InDesign
12/28/2012 11:59:27,"Data Analysis, Data Visualization, Graphic Design","Excel, OpenOffice.org/Libre Office, Stata"
12/28/2012 11:59:44,Data Visualization,"R, Adobe Illustrator"
```

Read it into SPSS using the following syntax:

```
GET DATA
  /TYPE=TXT
  /FILE="path\to\CourseInterestSurvey.CSV"
  /DELCASE=LINE
  /DELIMITERS=","
  /QUALIFIER='"'
  /ARRANGEMENT=DELIMITED
  /FIRSTCASE=2
  /IMPORTCASE=ALL
  /VARIABLES=
  Timestamp A19
  CourseInterest A49
  Software A41.
CACHE.
EXECUTE.
DATASET NAME DataSet2 WINDOW=FRONT.
LIST.
```

It currently looks like the image below--three columns (one timestamp, and two with the data we want):

[image]

Working with some syntax from [here](http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/Syntax-to-reverse-concatenate-in-SPSS-td1079531.html), we can split the cells up as follows:

```
* We know the string does not excede 50 characters.
* We got that information while we were reading our data in.
STRING #temp(a50). 
* We're going to work on the "CourseInterest" variable.
COMPUTE #temp=CourseInterest. 
* We're going to create 3 new variables with the prefix "CourseInterest".
* You should modify this according to the actual number of options your data has
* and the maximum length of one of the strings in your data.
VECTOR CourseInterest(3, a25). 
* Here's where the actual variable creation takes place.
LOOP #i = 1 TO 3. 
.  COMPUTE #index=index(#temp,","). 
.  DO IF   #index GT 0. 
.    COMPUTE CourseInterest(#i)=LTRIM(substr(#temp,1, #index-1)). 
.    COMPUTE #temp=substr(#temp, #index+1). 
.  ELSE. 
.    COMPUTE CourseInterest(#i)=LTRIM(#temp). 
.    COMPUTE #temp=''. 
.  END IF. 
END LOOP IF #index EQ 0. 
LIST.
```

The result:

[image]

This only addresses one column at a time, and I'm not familiar enough to modify it to work over multiple columns. However, if you were to switch over to R, I already have some [readymade](https://github.com/mrdwab/2657-R-Functions/blob/master/scripts/concat.split.R) [functions](https://github.com/mrdwab/2657-R-Functions/blob/master/scripts/multi.freq.table.R) to help deal with exactly these kinds of situations.

Comment: +1 - You could either use a loop outside of a do repeat, or write this up in a macro to modify it to work over multiple columns. Another way would be to have a do repeat just search for the particular strings and return dummy variables (which would be a nicer format for multiple response sets). This would be more up front work though, although likely necessary as some point anyway.

Comment: This looks good actually! Thank you I will try it tonight! One question: Do I keep the original Variable as well? If yes then why do I need it (since I now have seperate variables (1,2,3 etc)

Comment: @PanagiotisPalladinos, I wouldn't see any need for the original variables any longer, particularly since you have that information available as a Google Spreadsheet if you need it. The only use I can see really is tabulation of the *combination* of responses (since Google Forms already sorts the multiple responses in a consistent manner) rather than tabulation of each response.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no easy "built-in" way to achieve this, but it is certainly achievable with spreadsheet formulae, or Google Apps Script.

Using formulae, assuming your check box question lands in column D, this will produce a "normalised" list:

`=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCAENATE(D2:D&",");",")))`

and you can turn that into a two-column list and [QUERY](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1388882) it to return a table of frequencies:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(D2:D&",");","))&{"",""};"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 label Col1 'Item', count(Col2) 'Frequency'";0))`

If your locale uses a comma as a decimal separator, replace `{"",""}` with `{""\""}`.

Comment: Oh man you'd think that after 17 versions of SPSS they would implement checkboxes... Thx for your answer mate. I will try it and get back to you!

Comment: Oops sorry, I missed the SPSS tag, my answer is a solution within Google Spreadsheets. I'll leave it for now, but comment me back if you want me to remove it (happy to do so).

Comment: Google sheets adds a ", " between items, so you need to trim as well. My updated formula: `=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(Trim(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(RANGE&","),","))))&{"",""},"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 label Col1 'Topic', count(Col2) 'Votes'",0))`

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to split the fields into separate variables as described above.  Now define these variables as a multiple response set (Analyze > Tables > Multiple Response Sets), and you can analyze these with the CTABLES or MULT REPONSE procedures and graph them using the Chart Builder